# how to use shopping cart rules to restrict postcode

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, shopping-cart

We have small business and we deliver goods to only specific postcodes.How can i restrict purchase to only those postcodes.I have read that i can do it from shopping cart rules.So,I created one rule for postcode from shopping cart rules but I don't know from where i can add my postcodes and how to apply that rule to shipping and stop purchasing in other postcodes.
Please help.

Comment: Do you want to restrict customer for shipping method or payment method?

Comment: shipping method on the basis of postcodes

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative solution is you can use default **Table rate shipping method**, where you can enter all the zip codes in excel sheet and import the excel sheet.

[image]

below links will give you complete information  :

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

https://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/

Also one more option is you can use below extension to achieve this  :

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-1.html